# When I do git diff | mate2 it opens Textmate but doesn't show me the diff

Tags: git, textmate2

I have tried all manner of `git diff` commands.

From using the actual commit hashes:

```
$ git diff e2951679823lkdasdkjn38 7jhlkdjhlakj3kl2jlj2a90 | mate2
```

To using two branches:

```
$ git diff master develop | mate2
```

Both of which just launch Textmate2 but don't show me the files I want to see.

I would like to be able to do a diff on my `Gemfile.lock` over the last say two or 3 commits in Textmate. How do I do that?

Comment: What arguments does mate2 expect?

Comment: The same arguments that any text editor expects when passing files to it via the command-line, I presume. If I want to edit a file from the command line, I just do `mate2 <filepath>`.

Comment: What's mate2?  Did you rename mate?

Comment: Yes, I have TextMate2 & Textmate1 installed, so I have two aliases. `mate` and `mate2`.

Comment: try `mate2 -`. `-` means standard input. The result should be something like `$ git diff master develop | mate2 -`

Comment: I get this error: `$ git diff master develop | mate2 -
The file /myapp/- does not exist.`

Comment: "$ git diff master develop | mate2" Works for me, with or without a - at the end. Is this still a problem for you in the latest version? (At this time of writing: 2.0-alpha.9489)

Answer (score 0):

Check out `mate -h`.  You can give TM2 a hint on the bundle you want to use with the `-t` switch. The following compares two branches, piping the output to TextMate in diff mode:

```
git diff master develop | mate -t source.diff
```

To see only a single path, you do the following:

```
git diff master develop -- <paths> | mate -t source.diff
```

This is a fairly common syntax for a number of other commands as well (like git log).  You can read more about it on the [git diff manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

```
git diff [options] [<commit>] [--] [<path>…]
git diff [options] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>…]
git diff [options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…]
git diff [options] <blob> <blob>
git diff [options] [--no-index] [--] <path> <path>
```